# scipy binned statistcs future warning

Tags: numpy, scipy, future-warning

function binned statistics from scipy.stats raise warning:

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scipy/stats/_binned_statistic.py:607: FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. In the future this will be interpreted as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an error or a different result.
  result = result[core]

to reproduce just run stats.binned_statistics documentation example:

```
values = [1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.5, 3.0]
st.binned_statistic([1, 1, 2, 5, 7], values, 'sum', bins=2)
```

I tried to foollow the warning by:

```
values = np.array((1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.5, 3.0))
st.binned_statistic(np.array((1, 1, 2, 5, 7)), values, 'sum', bins=2)
```

But it seems no results. How to ommit this message without global filtering future warning

scipy 1.1.0 numpy 1.15.0 python 3.5, ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I get the same warning when using `seaborn` `distplot`.

Answer (score 2):

It is safe to disregard this warning, which is specific to the combination of scipy <=1.1.0 and numpy >=1.15.0.
It should be gone in scipy 1.2.0, when it's released.